# Paging and error

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to code a little paging system, but as far as things go, I'm getting an error. Here's my code:

```
<!-- something before that's working well -->    
else{
    include('head.php');
    if(empty($_GET['pg'])){ $_GET['pg'] = 0 ;}
    $offset = $_GET['pg'] * 5;
    $query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5 OFFSET :n');
    $query->bindParam(':n', $offset);
    $query->execute();
?>
<body>
<?php 
    while ($data = $query->fetch()){
        echo '<article>'.$data['content'].'</article>';
       }}?>

   </body>
```

So I simply want to display 5 articles by page. That is to say, I want the last 5 articles on index page (that is page 0), then the next 5 articles on page 1 etc. So far, all I'm getting is this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''0'' at line 1' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/index.php:24 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/index.php(24): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/index.php on line 24

line 24 is `$query->execute();` instruction.

So I guess my question is: what's going on? Is my paging system going to work the way I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because the resulting sql has quote chars around the 0.

'SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5 OFFSET :n'
is turning into

'SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5 OFFSET "0"'
when the sql that you need is

'SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0'  -- with no quotes around the 0

Try this

```
$offset =  (int) ($_GET['pg'] * 5 ); // cast to an int so that you know its not a non-int value, then you don't need the protection of bind

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5 OFFSET ' . $offset;

$query = $db->prepare($sql);

$query->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
$offset = $_GET['pg'] * 5;
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5 OFFSET ':n'");
$query->execute(array(':n' => $offset);
```

EDIT:

OK, this code should work.

```
$sql = "SELECT `password` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = :username";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
$query = $stmt->execute(array(':username' => $username));
$rows = $query->fetchAll();
if (empty($rows)) {

}
```

Just modify it according to your needs.